# Regarding image Display from url in android

Tags: android

I want to display a list of image form url which I will get from xml file. How can I do that? Please assist me.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a library to do the work for you check out [DroidFu](http://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu). There's a writeup [here](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter).

Otherwise you'll have to spin off a new thread (probably using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) that does the HTTP get and assigns it to [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)s.

I know this is kind of high-level, but there is TONS of info out there about how to do HTTP gets and using AsyncTask.